# partition space in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and have some questions regarding the partition size.

[image]

As you can see SDA1 is just 291G but my hard drive is 320 GB.

[image]

So

1. Where did the remaining memory go ?
2. You can see sda1, sda2 and sda5. Where did sda3 and 4 go? I always thought it's sequential.
3. I understand what swap space is and why is it needed but what is extended partition and why do we need it?

Please do let me know if any other command I need to run to get additional info any1 might need to answer my doubts.

Comment: Please do not ask 3 questions in 1 - there should be one answer to one question.

Comment: All seemed kind of related to me atleast 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2):

The output of both `df -h` and `lsblk` will give us the size in [gibibyte (GiB)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte) where 1 GiB is 1.07374 GB.

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        55G  9,3G   43G  18% /
```

Using the option `-H` will output disk size to a base of 1000 (which is GB) to report the size of a drive as expected.

```
df -H
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        59G  9,9G   47G  18% /
```

For an output of `lsblk` in bytes rather than GiB use option `lsblk -b`.

To list all partitions we may give them to the `df` command e.g.

```
df /dev/sdb1 -H
```

Comment: Wow did not know options can be case sensitive and `h` and `H` could make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

To answer question 1, I would assume that the remaining memory can be attributed to the partitions other than sda1, but to verify I would use *gparted*. I find the program to be extremely reliable and if it doesn't help you find the sizes of your other partitions, then I do not know what else to recommend. If you're only using the command line, then check out *parted*.

I have never used fdisk, so I cannot properly answer question 2. I do know, however, that the fdisk program can be buggy, according to the "BUGS" section of its man page. The page recommends other fdisk variants, such as *cfdisk*, and also recommends *parted*.

I hope my answers help you to find a solution to this issue.